# Limsup Commutative Property

Tags: analysis

Could somebody prove that the limsup commutes? For example, if I have $\text{limsup}_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{n^22^n},$ I want to do $\text{limsup}_{n\to\infty}2 * \text{limsup}_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{n^2}.$ Thanks!

Also, when can we interchange limsup and lim (like just consider lim and not limsup)?

Comment: $\sqrt[n]{n^22^n}=2\times\sqrt[n]{n^2}$, so limits are equal.  The extra limsup in the second expression is superfluous.

Comment: It is always true that $\operatorname{limsup}_{n \to \infty} ka_n = k \operatorname{limsup}_{n \to \infty} a_n$ for constants $k \ge 0$. If $k$ were not constant, then that would be a whole other matter, but since you have a constant factor of $2$, feel free to bring it out the front.